# ASP.NET Core 6 hits controller every 2 calls in Azure App Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session, azure-web-app-service

I have a controller `AddDocumentsToTempFolder` where one or multiple files should be stored in an Tempfolder so I can save all selected file when needed. This works fine on local site.

Now when I publish it into Azure as an App Service, this controller is being skipped every 2 calls. But it still creates an temp folder with a new session id. And when I add again a new file it gets the previous session id. So basically when i save this Form it will get the wrong id and saves not all added Files.

I tried to Remotedebug with Visual Studio and found out that the breakpoints dont hit everytime it gets the wrong session id. Because of this skipping in the next call to save the files the Request.Form.Files is missing some of the addes files.

Here I have the Code of the Controller.

I hope someone can help me.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddDocumentsToTempFolder(IList<IFormFile> files, BoardType targetBoardType)
{
    List<Document> DocList = new();
    Document doc = default;
    PageType targetedController = new();
    
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString(PredefineMessages.FOLDERSESSIONID)))
        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString(PredefineMessages.FOLDERSESSIONID, _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Id);

    foreach (IFormFile file in files)
    {
        if (file.Length > 0)
        {
            BinaryReader reader = new(file.OpenReadStream());
            var data = reader.ReadBytes((int)file.Length);
            DocList.Add(new Document()
            {
                Name = file.FileName,
                ContentType = file.ContentType,
                FileContent = data,
                DocId = new Guid(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString(PredefineMessages.FOLDERSESSIONID))
            });

            switch (targetBoardType)
            {
                case BoardType.Topic:
                    targetedController = PageType.Board;
                    break;
                case BoardType.Task:
                    targetedController = PageType.Board;
                    break;
                case BoardType.Decision:
                    targetedController = PageType.Board;
                    break;
                case BoardType.Information:
                    targetedController = PageType.Board;
                    break;
                case BoardType.Project:
                    targetedController = PageType.Project;
                    break;
                case BoardType.Meeting:
                    targetedController = PageType.Meetings;
                    break;
            }

            doc = _commonHelper.UploadFileToTempPath(file, Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString(PredefineMessages.FOLDERSESSIONID), targetBoardType.ToString())).Result;

            var tempFile = DocList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FilePath is null);
            tempFile.FilePath = doc.FilePath;
            tempFile.Id = doc.Id;
        }
    }

    var fileData = new FileViewModel {
            Documents = DocList,
            TargetedController = targetedController,
            BoardType = targetBoardType 
    };
    
    return PartialView(PredefineMessages.DOCUMENTLISTPARTIALVIEWSTRING, fileData);
}   
    
public async Task<Document> UploadFileToTempPath(IFormFile file, string tempFolderPath)
{
    var fileName = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", file.FileName, "_", _random.Next(0, 1000));
    string filePath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(tempFolderPath, fileName));

    if (!Directory.Exists(tempFolderPath))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(tempFolderPath);

    using Stream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
    await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);

    return new Document { FilePath = filePath, Id = fileName.Split('_').LastOrDefault() };
}
```

Comment: Could you please remove the images and post the code in the question itself?

Answer (score 0):

I could find a solution. The problem was within the Azure App Service. Somehow there was a second deployment in the meta of the code. So it switched between these uploads every call and had thus every time a different Session Id.